# What does Qubitization mean?

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation

I was listening to an advanced lecture about quantum computing, when the professor introduced a chapter called "Qubitization and the quantum singular value transform", but never really cared to define what qubitization means. After some research I came across the term in it's first usage by Chuang in 2016 I believe in this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.06546.pdf. However, I can't seem to see where the authors actually give a proper definition in the above paper. Any help on what is commonly referred to as qubitization is much apprectiated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It just means that you block encode the matrix $A$ into a larger unitary matrix, $U_A$. That is,

$$ U_A = \begin{pmatrix} A & *\\ * & *\end{pmatrix}$$

where $*$ indicate arbitrary matrix elements. Note that each unitary matrix is already a trivial block encoding of itself. Once this is done, you can implement
$$ U = \begin{pmatrix} P(A) & *\\ * & *\end{pmatrix}$$
where $P(A)$ is a polynomial (usually Chebyshev) approximation of some function you want to implement. For instance, if you want to find $A^{-1}$ so that you can solve the linear system of equations $Ax =b$ then $P(A)$ is the polynomial (usually Chebyshev)approximation of $f(x) = 1/x$. This implementation can be done through a quantum circuit of the form
[image]

The key point is that the Quantum Signal Processing theorem tells us that the above sequence can approximate rich space of functions by modifying the  sequence  $\{\varphi_i \}_{i=0}^d$. Furthermore, this can be done efficiently as well as noted in the paper "[Efficient phase-factor evaluation in quantum signal processing](https://escholarship.org/content/qt83b2r9mc/qt83b2r9mc.pdf)" by Dong et al.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - in the context of my lecture, this does make a lot of sense now! One further question: So as far as I can see there's no restrictions on the operator A we want to block encode and what do you mean by "information of your system"? Also the $\phi$ should be $\varphi$ and start from the index 0 as far as I am concerned.

Comment: @Lagrange What I meant to say is that $A$ represents the problem you are trying to solve. For instance, it could be the electronic Hamiltonian of a chemical system. Sorry if I have worded it confusingly. And yes, φ ranging from $0$ to $d$ is correct.

Comment: The answer is not correct as it addresses the question "what block encoding is".

Answer (score 2):

Qubitization is a way to assemble a very specific block encoding $W_A$ (also known as *Szegedy quantum walk operator*). It was introduced in Chapter 4 of the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.06546). A friendly introduction can be found in Section II of the  [Linear T complexity paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.03662) or in Section II.B of this [lattice paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.11637). (More precisely, Fig 1 in the [Linear T complexity paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.03662) provides an extremely efficient implementation of $W_A$ based on the same ingredients, PREPARE and SELECT, which one would use to construct $U_A$ using the Linear Combination of Unitaries; Fig 3 in the [lattice paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.11637) explains how $W_A$ can be made out of an arbitrary $U_A$.)

**BASICS**

$U_A$ is a block encoding of $A$ if
$$
A/\alpha = ({\langle 0|}_a\otimes 1_s) U_A (|0\rangle_a\otimes 1_s) \,,
$$
where $|0\rangle_a$ is the ancillary qubit register and $1_s$ is the identity operator on the system register. From now on assume for simplicity that $\alpha=1$.

This imples that
$$
U_A |0\rangle_a|\psi\rangle_s = 
        |0\rangle_a (A |\psi\rangle_s) - |\bot\rangle_{as}\,,
$$
where the state $|\bot\rangle_{as}$ is "perpendicular" to $|0\rangle_a$ in the sense that $({\langle 0|}_a\otimes 1_s)|\bot\rangle_{as}=0$, and the minus sign is conventional.

Now, let's consider a particular case of the equation above and choose $|\psi\rangle_s$ to be $|\lambda\rangle_s$, the eigenvector of $A$:

$$
U_A |0\rangle_a|\lambda\rangle_s = \lambda\,|0\rangle_a|\lambda\rangle_s - \sqrt{1-\lambda^2} |\bot^\lambda\rangle_{as}
    \,,
$$
where the superscript in $|\bot^\lambda\rangle_{as}$ indicates that the vector $|\bot\rangle_{as}$ corresponds to the case $|\psi\rangle_s=|\lambda\rangle_s$.

Note that if one further applies $U_A$ to any of the two equations above, the RHS will generally contain more than two terms, since it is not obvious how $U_A$ acts on the perpendicular vector. (It would be more fruitful to act on these equations with $U_A^\dagger$, as described in Section 7.4 [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Elinlin/qasc/qasc_notes.pdf), and this would eventually lead to the construction described below.)

**QUBITIZATION**

As was stated above, Qubitization allows one, starting from $U_A$, to obtain another block encoding $W_A$, possessing the following extra property:
$$
\begin{aligned}
W_A |0\rangle_a|\lambda\rangle_s &= \lambda\,|0\rangle_a|\lambda\rangle_s - \sqrt{1-\lambda^2} |\bot^\lambda\rangle_{as}
\\&= \left( \lambda\, |0\rangle_a - \sqrt{1-\lambda^2} |\bot^\lambda\rangle_a
 \right)|\lambda\rangle_s
    \,,
\end{aligned}
$$
where
$$
|\bot^\lambda\rangle_{as} = |\bot^\lambda\rangle_{a}|0\rangle_{s}
=
(1_a\otimes\langle\lambda|_s)\frac{\lambda 1_{as} - W_A  }{\sqrt{1-\lambda^2}}|0\rangle_a|\lambda\rangle_s\,.
$$

Here for simplicity I keep the convention that the ancillary qubit is in the all-zero state. In fact, starting from $U_A$ which assumes all zero ancillas, leads to $W_A$ which has one ancilla in the $|+\rangle$ state. Also here I am overall not very careful about the dimension of ancillary register.

The significance of this construction is given by equations above: *while consecutive applications of $U_A$ generally mess up the structure of the state it acts upon, the consecutive action of $W_A$ is simple.*
When acting on the state $|0\rangle_a|\lambda\rangle_s$, the block encoding $W_A$ only induces a 2D rotation in the ancillary space but does not affect $|\lambda\rangle_s$. This implies that for a fixed $\lambda$ the action of $W_A$ is given by a $2\times2$ matrix acting on $\{|0\rangle_a,|\bot^\lambda\rangle_{a}\}$:
$$
\left(1_a \otimes \langle\lambda'|_s\right) W_A \left(1_a \otimes |\lambda\rangle_s\right) = W_A^{(\lambda)} \delta_{\lambda \lambda'}\,,
$$
where
$$
W_A = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & - \sqrt{1-\lambda^2} \\ \sqrt{1-\lambda^2} & \lambda \end{pmatrix}\,.
$$

Finally, the action of $W_A$ on arbitrary state of the form $|0\rangle_a|\psi\rangle_s$ is given by a block-diagonal matrix, with blocks of size $2\times2$, each corresponding to different eigenvalues $\lambda$.